# How to Retrieve even rows in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

table A

```
columna   
---------
   A
   B            
   C
   :
   :
   Z
```

Here is how to select even rows. I've written a query like this

```sql
select * from (select row_number()over(order by no asc ) as number   
  from number 
 where mod(number,2)=0)as even
```

It isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
select *  
  from 
(
  select *, row_number() over (order by columna) as rnum   
    from tablea
) q
 where mod(rnum, 2) = 0
```

Output:

```
| NO | RNUM |
|----|------|
|  B |    2 |
|  D |    4 |
|  F |    6 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c656b/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> desc member_list
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 E_MAIL                                   VARCHAR2(50)
 NAME                                     VARCHAR2(50)


select e_mail from (select rownum row_num, e_mail from member_list)
where mod(row_num,2) = 0 -- EVEN
```

Gave you an example Try this

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *
    ,      ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY no)AS RowNum
    FROM number t
)
SELECT cte.* FROM cte
WHERE  mod(RowNum,2) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

don't know abt postgres but in oracle you can do like this

```
SELECT * FROM   
    (SELECT columna, ROWNUM RNUM  
            FROM tableA 
            ORDER BY columna)   
    where MOD(RNUM,2)=0
```